# Recording UI interactions (from XCUITesting) from outside of Xcode?

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

Is it possible to trigger the generation of interaction code without pressing the record button within Xcode? I'd like to hide the IDE from UI testers and, if possible, enable them to edit the test visually.

Comment: Did you find anything that allowed you to do that?